# Program halts when executing "and" instruction (cortex-m3)

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

I've got the following code:

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb
@ ...
ldr   r1, =0x40010800
ldr   r0, [r1]
ldr   r2, =0x44044444
and   r0, r2
orr   r0, #0x200000
str   r0, [r1]
@ ...
```

I'm debugging via gdb and openocd.
If I get to the `and   r0, r2` statement and enter next, the program is halted, the following is displayed:

```
19      and   r0, r2
(gdb) next
halted: PC: 0x080000fe
halted: PC: 0x080000fe
halted: PC: 0x080000fe
...
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, as I don't see anything wrong with the instruction; so I'm wondering what the problem might be.

**Edit** (minimal reproducible example):

```
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

.word    0x20000400
.word    0x080000ed
.space   0xe4

@ activate clock for GPIOa (interestingly removing this section solves the problem)
ldr   r0, =0x40021018
ldr   r1, [r0]
orr   r1, #0x4
str   r0, [r1]    

@ configure PA5 as 2 MHz push-pull Output
ldr   r1, =0x40010800
ldr   r2, =0x44044444
ldr   r0, [r1]
and   r0, r2
ldr   r2, =0x44244444
orr   r0, r2
str   r0, [r1]

b     .
```

binary built with

```
$ arm-none-eabi-as -g prog.S -o prog.o 
$ arm-none-eabi-ld prog.o -o prog.elf -Ttext=0x08000000
```

Debugged with the following commands:

```
$ openocd -f interface/stlink-v2.cfg -f target/stm32f1x.cfg
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb prog.elf
(gdb) target remote :3333
(gdb) monitor reset halt
(gdb) stepi
...
```

The Mikrocontroller used is an *STM32F103RB*.

Despite the debugger beeing stuck, the program works (LED is turned one after the second *stepi* over the *and* instruction).

Dissassembly (`x/ni $pc`):

```
=> 0x80000ec <_stack+133693676>:        movs    r0, #4
   0x80000ee <_stack+133693678>:        ldr     r1, [pc, #16]   ; (0x8000100 <_stack+133693696>)
   0x80000f0 <_stack+133693680>:        str     r0, [r1, #0]
   0x80000f2 <_stack+133693682>:        ldr     r0, [pc, #16]   ; (0x8000104 <_stack+133693700>)
   0x80000f4 <_stack+133693684>:        ldr     r1, [pc, #16]   ; (0x8000108 <_stack+133693704>)
   0x80000f6 <_stack+133693686>:        str     r0, [r1, #0]
   0x80000f8 <_stack+133693688>:        movs    r0, #32
   0x80000fa <_stack+133693690>:        ldr     r1, [pc, #16]   ; (0x800010c <_stack+133693708>)
   0x80000fc <_stack+133693692>:        str     r0, [r1, #0]
   0x80000fe <_stack+133693694>:        b.n     0x80000fe <_stack+133693694>
   0x8000100 <_stack+133693696>:        asrs    r0, r3, #32
   0x8000102 <_stack+133693698>:        ands    r2, r0 
   0x8000104 <_stack+133693700>:        add     r4, r8 
   0x8000106 <_stack+133693702>:        add     r4, r4
   0x8000108 <_stack+133693704>:        lsrs    r0, r0, #32  
   0x800010a <_stack+133693706>:        ands    r1, r0  
   0x800010c <_stack+133693708>:        lsrs    r4, r1, #32  
   0x800010e <_stack+133693710>:        ands    r1, r0
```

Comment: What happens when you try to single step with `stepi`?  Please also make sure that the source is the same as the code gdb tries to step through; it can happen for the two to get out of sync, causing weird errors like those you observe.

Comment: With `stepi` it always displays the same line in the source code (`19     and r0, r2`)

Comment: @fuz I recompiled/-built the binary and checked that it is the correct source-file, the error still persists.

Comment: Well that's weird.  Could you make a [mcve] if possible?

Comment: Can you check disassembly e.g. with `x/i $pc`?

Comment: when you run it without using gdb what happens?

Comment: Use `layout reg` or other GDB disassembly so you don't need to trust debug info / source lines. (And use `stepi` to step by instructions, not source lines).  When your debugger shows you something that doesn't make sense, something (like debug info) might be wrong with your tools.

Comment: @fuz I added one in the question.

Comment: @some_user I've moved to reopen the question.  Very interesting.  Could this be due to some interrupts arriving or due to a watchdog timer expiring or something like this?

Comment: @fuz Well I found a mistake - I mixed up the registers for the _str_ instruction in line 13 -,but strangely I can't even seem to reproduce the original bug anymore.

Comment: I did a full chip erase and nothing worked anymore (something like `0xfffffffe  at ??` after every _stepi_), but after restarting my computer everything worked perfectly, and the bug seems to have gone away.

Comment: @some_user How very strange.